Celery with Django memory leak problem. Just can't figure out what is happening
`Celery is behaving weird. It is using 5.5 gb which is around 90% of ram during execution on server and it is slowing down server performance.
Debug is set to False.
Also, I set max_tasks_per_child to 2, but it is releasing memory after completing the task. I want to make it to use less memory, and it is executing about 600 seconds to complete the task.
celery==5.1.2
Django==3.2.4
here is my task that I have tried:`
def check_sites2(url):

    session = get_session()
    headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)         Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
}
    try:
        response = session.head(url.url, headers=headers, timeout=21)
    except requests.exceptions.SSLError as e:
        response = session.head(url.url, verify=False, headers=headers, timeout=21)
    except Exception as e:
        print("Something went wrong {e}")


def download_all_sites(sites):
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        executor.map(check_sites2, sites)

@shared_task
def api_checker_stats():

    api_list = URL.objects.filter(active=True) # about 500 url objects
    download_all_sites(api_list)`
    return 1

